# Autocomplete textbox based on dropdownlist selected text - Jquery MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

I have a dropdownlist and textbox. Based on the selection of dropdownlist I need to do autocomplete for the textbox.

eg: If I selected *Name* in dropdownlist, textbox autocomplete value should be *name*, if I selected *City* then textbox autocomplete should be *city*.

Please help me to do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Autocomplete Test</title>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/Search/ProcessTheForm" method="post">
        <input id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" type="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#searchTerm").autocomplete({
                source: "/Search/AutocompleteSuggestions",
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item) {
                        $("#searchTerm").val(ui.item.value);
                        $("form").submit();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

public JsonResult AutocompleteSuggestions(string term)
{
    var suggestions = _searchRepository.GetAutoCompleteSearchSuggestion(term);
    return Json(suggestions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

http://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2011/02/04/Autocomplete-dropdown-with-jQuery-UI-and-MVC

http://instinctcoder.com/asp-net-mvc-4-jquery-autocomplete-dropdownlist/